# Add suffix to all subdirectories in current directory in Linux

Tags: linux, file-rename, batch-rename, mv

In current directory: folders: 001, 002, 003, 004......etc. I want to add the suffix '_ses-1' to all folders and it makes for example 001_ses-1

Tried

```
for d in *; do mv "$d" "${d}_ses-1"; done


find ./ -type d -exec bash -c mv "$folder" "${folder}_ses-1"
```

All failed and would like some help to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command (`for`) won't match only directories.

The second (`find`) is problematic if you have nested directories.

If you don't have nested folders, you can use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mv {} {}_ext \;
```

Comment: thanks, it worked! I think maxdepth 1 helps even it is nested

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a one-off task, and it doesn't need to recurse, one trick is to pipe the output of `ls` into a text file, run a macro (e.g. in vim) to transform them to be the correct `mv` command, then run the whole thing as a script.

Another option is to use bash to generate each command (similar to what you have already tried) as a separate `mv` command and pipe into a file which you then run as a script.

Answer (score 0):

I like the `find ./` approach, but it likely finds `.` and `..` then fails on moving them.

`find ./ -type d ! -name . ! -name .. -exec bash -c mv "$folder" "${folder}_ses-1"`

For the `for d in *;`  method, you'd want to do this to iterate over the list:

```
for d in `ls -1`; do mv "$d" "${d}_ses-1"; done
```

Comment: Warning: parsing `ls` is hard: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @Mathieu perhaps, but `ls -1` for this specific case, without whitespace in the directory names, should not present any issues. I typically prefer `find`.

Comment: thanks! the second one worked. but since I have other .lsf files in the same directory.  I have to reverse the rename process for those files.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rename` command, which can be used like so: `find ... | xargs rename ...`. The `rename` command has several implementations, and is very powerful. It can be used for much more complex operations than a simple `mv`.

Example:

```
# Create a tiny test with 4 input directories:

$ mkdir 001 002 003 004

$ ls -d 00[1-4]*
001  002  003  004

# Do a dry run first using -n option:

$ find . -type d -name '00[1-4]' | xargs rename -n 's/$/_ses-1/'
'./001' would be renamed to './001_ses-1'
'./003' would be renamed to './003_ses-1'
'./004' would be renamed to './004_ses-1'
'./002' would be renamed to './002_ses-1'

# Actually rename for real:

$ find . -type d -name '00[1-4]' | xargs rename 's/$/_ses-1/'

# Confirm the results:

$ ls -d 00[1-4]*
001_ses-1  002_ses-1  003_ses-1  004_ses-1
```

Note that `rename` can be installed easily, for example with `conda`:

```
conda install rename
```

**SEE ALSO:**

`rename` manual (very helpful):

```
rename --man
```

For example:

```
-n, --dry-run, --just-print
    Show how the files would be renamed, but don't actually do anything.
```